# How can I scroll the grid programatically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am generating grid from `c#` code in `WPF` application. My `grid` is dynamically generated using the code and it contains many rows. I want to `scroll the grid to some specific element` in the grid so user can see specific element as a first record in grid. Can you please help us that how can we scroll the grid programatically in WPF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252408/programmatically-scrolling-wpf-4-datagrid-to-end

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Will DataGrid.ScrollIntoView work for you? The first parameter(item) is the element you want to show.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Scrolls the System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid vertically and horizontally
    //     to display a cell for the specified data item and column.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   item:
    //     The data item to bring into view.
    //
    //   column:
    //     The column to bring into view.
    public void ScrollIntoView(object item, DataGridColumn column);
```