# XAML - Binding WPF DataGridView scroll event

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, scroll, datagridview

I have a WPF DataGrid. I set the vertical scrollbar's visibility to Hidden -- I want the user to scroll up and down using Button controls that are separate from the Datagrid itself, but I cannot figure out how to access the relevant properties.

I'd also like to do this without code-behind on the view file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it programmatically, you'd need to get to the `ScrollViewer` inside, as demonstrated here: [Programmatically scrolling WPF 4 DataGrid to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252408/programmatically-scrolling-wpf-4-datagrid-to-end)

```
ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer()
{
   if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount (this) == 0) return null;
   var x = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild (this, 0);
   if (x == null) return null;
   if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount (x) == 0) return null;
   return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild (x, 0) as ScrollViewer;
}
```

Then you could use the `ScrollViewer` functions [ScrollToHorizontalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx), [ScrollToVerticalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx).

To control this via XAML, you'd need an attached behavior. Here is a blog post which covers one way to do that: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/07/21/exposing-and-binding-to-a-silverlight-scrollviewers-scrollbars.html