# Datagrid scrollbar buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

I am practicing with c# WPF DataGrid, when I have many rows, the vertical scrollbar is activated. How to know that I am moving the scrollbar button from top to bottom with the left mouse button?

I'm new with WPF, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Did you already web-search these?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252408/programmatically-scrolling-wpf-4-datagrid-to-end    --   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793717/how-to-find-that-scrollviewer-is-scrolled-to-the-end-in-wpf

Comment: I don't follow your question. What exactly are you doing, what happens, what do you expect to happen differently?

Comment: Following the suggestion of Andy I'll  change my question with more details of my problem and eliminate this one.